# Re-install drivers in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, bluetooth, hp, capslock

My HP laptop behaves weirdly after I disconnect my Bluetooth earphones. The bar shows WiFi connected, but the internet no longer works. Also, the Caps Lock starts blinking as 2 back to back and 1 delayed light. It also used to hang until I removed the battery and re-inserted it. But it no longer hangs now. Just the Internet not working and Caps Lock blinking issue.

I have had no updates recently, and so have no idea what went wrong. I am suspecting there may be an issue with the Bluetooth driver. But do not know how to re-install it. Any help shall be appreciated.

Edit : Here is my System Information

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: HP
        Product Name: HP Laptop 15g-br0xx
        Version: Type1ProductConfigId
        Serial Number: CND7270G54
        UUID: F8DAC31D-9449-E711-B753-F430B9829DB3
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: 2JR16PA#ACJ
        Family: 103C_5335KV HP Notebook
```

[image]

Comment: You mention at least 3 different symptom/problems. The blinking light usually means that you've had a kernel crash... and I'll bet... the only way to recover is to power off and reboot, yes?

Comment: @heynnema I just mentioned all the symptoms I encountered. As for the booting, I've already tried it but didn't resolve my problem. Anything else you could suggest?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact series and model # of your HP laptop.

Comment: @heynnema there you go!

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I'm not finding that exact model at the HP web site. Please look at the bottom of the laptop, and give me the EXACT model #, and serial #, and I'll try to find it that way.

Comment: @heynnema I already provided the model and serial number in the System Information

Comment: I suspect that the info might be different on the tag... as I tried to use all of the information you provided, but at the HP web site, I was getting conflicting info back. Hence my request.

Comment: Are you using Wayland intentionally... that is... have you selected Wayland at the cogwheel settings icon on the login screen?

Comment: No, I haven't selected Wayland.

Comment: I also have matched the model and serial numbers as you asked.. It is exactly the same at the bottom of the laptop as the System Information mentions

Comment: I asked about Wayland because it crashed yesterday.

Comment: Please see my answer. If I have the correct web page, and the BIOS update solves the problem, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

HP Laptop 15g-br0xx

You have BIOS F.10.

There **appears** to be a newer BIOS available, version F.65 Rev A, dated Jan 10, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-15g-br000-laptop-pc/15551414) ***.

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

*** Normally I don't have as much trouble identifying the correct BIOS, but this model/serial #s give mixed results at the HP web site... so double-check my results.

**Wayland**

Looking in /var/crash, we see that Wayland crashed yesterday, Oct 6. You confirmed that you have not selected Wayland at the login screen.

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.

Comment: ```If you do not see the version of your operating system (OS) listed on the software download site for your HP product, HP does not have any downloadable software or drivers for your product for that operating system.``` Regarding the HP page, it doesn't seem like they provide drivers for any OS other than Windows

Comment: @SwatiSrivastava That's normal. Just select "Windows" and "Windows 10", and you'll see it.

Comment: Yes, I got to the download part of BIOS update. Thanks for that

Comment: For the ```WaylandEnable=false``` part, it raises an error ```Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported``` when I try to save the changes in the ```custom.conf```

Comment: @SwatiSrivastava Those are bogus warning messages. Check the file again and see if your edits are there. Let me know how it goes after the BIOS update.

Comment: I completed the BIOS update and it seems that the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for helping me throughout the procedure.

Comment: @SwatiSrivastava You're very welcome. Thanks for the update, and the accept!